# Eliminar un servicio y proceso en windows 10

Tags: windows, consola, windows10, servicio, filesystem

Hola a todos Hace años desistale eñ antivirus McAfee en windows 10, pero cuando voy a servicios y procesos me siguen apareciendo varios servicios y procesos de McAfee. En concreto :

McAfee Process Validation Server

McAfee validation Trust Protection Service

Cuando lo desistale elimine las carpetas que se quedan en Progam Files y Archivos de Programas.
Pero si me voy a Systen 32 que hay un ejecutable llamado  **mfevtps** pero no me deja eliminarlos, me dice:

> La accion no se puede completar porque McAfee Validation Trust Protection Server tiene abierto
> el archivo

Si inicio el administrado de tareas y voy a Procesos me aparecen los servicios comentados. Si intento detenerlos me dice **Acceso denegado** si me voy a Servicios que tambien aparece ,me responde los mismo. Mi cuenta es de administrador lo he comprobando poniendo en la consola el com ando **net user**.

No se que puedo hacer solo me pasa, he probado con otros servicio y proceso y puedo detener,iniciar etc.

¿Que puedo hacer para eliminar estos servicios que no uso ya?

Comment: Utiliza la ***herramienta de eliminación de McAfee*** a ver si te funciona [Herramienta de eliminacion](http://download.mcafee.com/products/licensed/cust_support_patches/MCPR.exe), [Guía de como usarla (Método 2)](https://www.mcafee.com/support/?articleId=TS101331&page=shell&shell=article-view), luego reinicia la pc y cuentas si te funciono, Saludos.

Comment: 1) hacer lo que te dicen en el primer comentario; 2) ir al sitio https://superuser.com/ y hacer la misma pregunta; 3) formatea es a xuxa...

Comment: 4) preguntarle a los señores de McAfee, que seguro saben mas que nosotros?

Comment: Puedes probar a arrancar en "modo a prueba de fallos" (linea de comandos) y eliminar/renombrar el ficheros o ficheros que están bloqueados. La siguente prueba sería arrancar con un CD/USB tipo "Hiren's BootCD" (https://www.hiren.info/) que te permita acceder a los discos  (y probar a borrar/renombrar esos ficheros bloquedos).

Comment: Hola Germán no he podido responder antes. Si lo hice así y funciono, pude eliminar los archivos y los servicios si aparecen, no se ya por que, pero están detenidos. Además elimine el navegador del AVG, que pasa lo mismo aunque lo desistales se queda el servicio activo. Gracias